# Coloring Multiple Bricks in LEGO Digital Draw

Tags: software, ldd, colour

I made the mistake of not coloring as I went while building a large object in LEGO Digital Designer.  I don't want to spend hours coloring each individual brick.  Is there a way I can box select the bricks and apply a color to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

I'm using:

- Version (Program): 4.3.11.
- Version (Brick): 2670.
- OS: Windows.

**Pre Setup:**

We're using *Extended Mode* (Black Backsplash) of LDD, so we can have full access to all colors.  I have not tested the other two modes, *Default* (Blue Backsplash) or *Mindstorms* (White Backsplash).

If the model is in *Default Mode*.  No problem.

- Copy the build to memory *(CTRL+A)* then *(CTRL+C)*;
- Open a new blank file in *Extended Mode*;
- and Paste from memory *(CTRL+P)*;
- Give file a different name as not to overwrite the original;
- Re-save.

**Setup:**

- Use the "COLOR Selecting Tool" and select a piece's color you want to
  change.
- All of that color is now highlighted.
- Use the "Invert Selection Tool" to reverse highlight everything not
  that color.
- Use the "Hide Tool" to make everything not that color disappear.
- Use the "Single Selection Tool" to block select the visible pieces
  that are getting a color change.
- Use the "Paint Tool" and pick the new color being used.
- Click the "Show all hidden bricks" button.
- [image: ![![enter image description here]
- Done.

**In Program Example:**

**Goal:**  Switch *Mega-Man* blues into *Leaf Shield* greens.

**Setup:**

- Use the "COLOR Selecting Tool" and select a piece's color you want to
  change.
  [image]
- All of that color is now highlighted.
  [image]
- Use the "Invert Selection Tool" to reverse highlight everything not
  that color.
  [image]
- Use the "Hide Tool" to make everything not that color disappear.
  [image]
- Use the "Single Selection Tool" to block select the visible pieces
  that are getting a color change.
  [image]
- Use the "Paint Tool" and pick the new color being used.
  [image]
  [image]
- Click the "Show all hidden bricks" button.
  [image]
- Done.
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: thank you, a very good answer!